# C# Getting values from text file and parsing them to have currency symbol in a List Box

Tags: c#, arrays, parsing, listbox, currency-formatting

I wanted to know how to add a currency symbol to a parsed value that was put into a `List<>` to display it in a **"$18.00"** format rather than **18.0** which is what I have now.

I tried `.ToString("N2")` but it's not that simple. I'll copy and paste what I currently have, I'm not too good of a programmer so bear with me.

I get no errors but I tried tossing the `.ToString` at the end but naturally it can't be that symbol. Any help would be appreciated!

```
currentItem.Price = decimal.Parse(strArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
currentItem.Price = decimal.Parse(strArray[2]).ToString("C");
```

More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I gave that a shot but it gave me: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'.

Comment: Right, because to get the format you want will make it a **string** (eg. $18.00). Therefore, you wither want to switch your class to a string type or format your data at the last moment before it hits the UI.

Comment: So I should do something like,
     currentItem.Price = decimal.Parse(strArray[2]);
     currentItem.Price = decimal.Parse(strArray[2]).ToString("C");
In order to convert it to a decimal first? Or is that too simple minded? I'm just having trouble because it's an array, how should I go about formatting it before it gets to the UI?

Comment: That's your choice in the program, if you need the decimal data for other reasons (calculations ect.) Then keep it decimal otherwise change it to a string.

Comment: I still have no solution to this. Can you write out the actual code of what I should do? I do in fact need the decimal data for another fourth column. I still get an error, all I need to do is keep it as a decimal and convert it ToString("C").

Comment: I think you should submit a new question focused on the list aspect. You should expand your code example in that question and be clear about what you mean. I think your question, **"to display it in a "$18.00" format rather than 18.0"**, has been answered.